# ReactJS communication between sibling components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to communicate with one of the **sibling components** and **pass props** to other component. This has to be done using **router** concept.

Or else suggest me if any other way to pass an array to other sibling component please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you really want to be doing is passing a function from a parent component as props that changes state which the parent will then pass down to its children.

Answer (score 0):

In React data flows from parents to children via what is referred to as 'props'.

A parent child structure is when you add a component under another component like so:

```
<Parent>
  <Child />
</Parent>
```

You can then access the parent's data on the child element using this.props.'prop-name'.